# Show that $|a+b|>\epsilon \implies |a|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\lor|b|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$. How can we show that

$$|a+b|>\epsilon \implies |a|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\lor|b|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

I'm puzzled with this for hours, but I can't prove it myself. If I take an example I see it is true, but I think I'm confused by the absolute values. Please lead me through it step by step.

Comment: try a proof by contradiction, i.e. suppose that $|a|$ and $|b|$ are smaller or equal $\epsilon/2$

Comment: Try the contrapositive, that is, assume the conclusion is false, then show that the assumption can't be true either.

Answer (score 6):

If $|a|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|b|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|\le\epsilon$.

Comment: oooooooooooooooooopz, contrapositve...